# Haskell Unicode column name in ODBC

Tags: haskell, unicode, odbc, hdbc

I am trying to query some data from a MSSQL database through [HDBC](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC) and [ODBC](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-odbc). I have however run into a problem when trying to query data from a table with unicode in the column names.

Consider the following MWE:

```
mwe :: IConnection conn => conn -> IO [[SqlValue]]
mwe conn =
  do r <- quickQuery' conn
          "SELECT [Højde] FROM [Table]"
          []
     return r
```

When executing the above and passing it a connection object to the database i get the following error message:

```
*** Exception: SqlError {seState = "[\"42S22\",\"42000\"]", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg = "execute execute: [\"207: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'H\\195\\184jde'.\",\"8180: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.\"]"}
```

The relevant part most likely being that `H\\195\\184jde` is not a valid column name.

My research has mostly led to results about unicode in the parameters to the query. I have tried to use bytestrings instead of normal strings, but since the argument for `QuickQuery'` is a string that did not help.

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to check the *UNICODE AND BYTESTRINGS* section in the [Database.HDBC.SqlValue](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-2.4.0.3/docs/Database-HDBC-SqlValue.html) page.

Comment: @Redu I think the problem there is that while the parameters are of type `SqlValue` the query itself is just of type `String`:
`quickQuery' :: IConnection conn => conn -> String -> [SqlValue] -> IO [[SqlValue]] `

Comment: An idea. Perhaps you make `[Højde]` like `[?]` in the `String` argument and pass a `[toSql ("Højde" :: ByteString)]` as `SqlValue` argument instead of an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an MS SQL instance to test this, but the [code](https://github.com/hdbc/hdbc-odbc/blob/06833d77799f16634d2038bcdc308c35d4752cdd/Database/HDBC/ODBC/Statement.hsc#L150) in `HDBC-odbc` encodes the query using UTF-8.  Meanwhile, [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/programming-guidelines?view=sql-server-ver15#character-set-support) suggests that for modern ODBC drivers, the character set used for queries depends on the process locale at the time the driver is initialized.  If it's `"C"`, which is the usual process default, then the driver will use the UTF-8 character set.  However, if the process executes:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"")
```

before initializing the driver, and the current Windows locale is, say, English using the Latin-1 1252 code page, then the ODBC driver will expect Latin-1 encoded queries.  Unfortunately for you, the GHC runtime *does* run `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")`, so that's probably what's going wrong.

If you reset the locale to `"C"` at the start of `"main"`, that may fix the issue:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Control.Monad
import Foreign.C
import Foreign.Ptr

foreign import ccall "locale.h setlocale" c_setlocale :: CInt -> CString -> IO CString

setCLocale :: IO ()
setCLocale = do
  rc <- withCString "C" $ c_setlocale 0
  when (rc == nullPtr) $ error "setCLocale failed"

main = do
  setCLocale
  print "whatever"
```

I'm not sure if this will cause other problems (e.g., with terminal input/output).  If it does, you may be able to set the locale to `"C"` before initializing the driver and then reset it to `""` right after.

Comment: That did not seem to do the trick. I tried both your code as well as the [setlocale](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/setlocale-1.0.0.9) hackage I found by searching setLocale. Using this package i was able to determine what my current locale string is: `LC_COLLATE=C;LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C`